# How to generate RSS using Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I use Asp.net Web Forms and C# 4.

I have content in DataBase table and I would like publish it as RSS for my website.

My questions:

- Does Asp.Net framework provide a namespace or tool to automatically
     doing it?
- In case no, could you point me out a good tutorial or tool?
- I read the article: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/22/Awesome-ASP.NET-2.0-RSS-Tool_2D00_Kit-Released.aspx
     this tool is for Asp.Net 2.0 could be used nowadays or is out of date?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do it by hand - use the built-in System.ServiceModel.Syndication classes to generate the feed for you. Then you know it's compliant with whichever format (RSS or ATOM) you generate.

Here's an article that walks you through it:

[How to create a syndication feed for your website][1]

[1]: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/How-to-create-a-syndication-feed-for-your-website.aspx [NOT WORKING]

Comment: Thanks Matt, Tutorial is great, I was able to do the script in less than two hours thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, MSDN has a relatively-straightforward tutorial on how to generate RSS 2.0 from ASP.NET, found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478968.aspx. It's really not terribly hard, so I would recommend doing it if you're wanting to learn something.

Comment: Yeah I followed this one and it was really easy

Answer (score 0):

You can found this tool very useful

[Creating SQL Based RSS Feed](http://www.dotnetforce.com/Content.aspx?t=a&n=204) **[DEAD LINK]**